List directories using shell and iterate using groovy
Can someone help on providing solution on this.
Im trying to list folders under a location(/root/var/) using shell script inside a groovy file.
Based on number of folders retrieved I have to iterate through the folder names alone(not the files inside the folders) using a For loop in groovy.
Below is my shell script in groovy file.
def folder location = "/root/var/*/"
List l = sh(script: "ls -d ${folderlocation}", returnStdout: true).trim().split('\n')
for(fldr in l){
Print(l)
}
The output I'm seeing for l is absolute path rather than the folder names.
Ex : /root/var/ contains lib as subdirectory.
I'm seeing l printed as /root/var/lib/
I'm expecting l to contain just lib not the absolute path or any other folder names if any.
Can someone pls help me.

If you use cd /root/var && ls -d ./* this will list all the the folders within /root/var without the leading path.
